# Laravel factory seeding error

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have four tables Book, Author, User, Rating where Author and User table have many to many relationship with Book table, and Rating table has a foreign key with book and user table. 5 Authors and users are created, now I want to create book and rating table together where user_id and book_id will be same for book and rating table! I'm trying this way but this give me error in Rating factory! May be variable scope! How to solve this?

> 'user_id' => $userRandom,

```
class BooksTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Book::class, 2)->create()->each(function ($book) {
            $author = App\Author::all();
            $user = App\User::all();
            $userRandom = $user->random();

            factory(App\Rating::class)->create([
                'book_id' => $book->id,
                'user_id' => $userRandom,
            ]);

            $book->authors()->save($author->random());
            $book->users()->save($userRandom);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also post the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that:

```
 'user_id' => $userRandom  // keeps exact id.
```

Otherwise You'll need to pass it like:

```
'user_id' => $userRandom->id
```

2) Make sure that You've defined `$fillable` attribute of `Rating` model.

You cannot just do create and pass some array (assoc) if You've not defined field names in `$fillable`.

> You may also use the create method to save a new model in a single line. 
>   The inserted model instance will be returned to you from the method. 
>   However, before doing so, you will need to specify either a fillable or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.
>
> So, to get started, you should define which model attributes you want to make mass assignable. 
>   You may do this using the $fillable property on the model.

Read about `Mass Assignment` https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent